# Android Project cloned from github giving error

Tags: android, eclipse

I have created android project, and added gitignore file from [gitignore](https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/master/Android.gitignore) and pushed to github.

Now I have cloned the same project into different system and imported into eclipse by following the instruction from [here](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.user%2Ftasks%2Ftasks-importproject.htm)

Now I am getting errors saying

> > Unable to resolve target 'android-19'
> >
> > WARNING: unable to write jarlist cache file /home/jayesh/Android Developement/TestApp1/bin/jarlist.cache

file permission of jarlist.cache -rwxr-xr-x

Can anyone help me with making the same project running.

I tried

1) eclipse > project > clean

2) right click on project > Android Tools > fix project properties

Android project link https://github.com/JayeshP/TestApp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you did not install the `SDK Platform` for kitkat in the SDK Manager. Install it or change the target SDK version.

Answer (score 0):

- When importing another project, make sure to enable "Copy projects in to workspace". This helps to solve many errors.
- Check buttons on top left pane of Eclipse, theres one named "Android SDK manager". Go in to SDK manager and install selected default ones and Android 4.4.2 Android 19.

Answer (score 0):

right click on you project -> properies -> resource

now, you should do two job:

1. go to "Android" and choose your suitable target
2. go to "java build path" and check suitable Android version ("Android4.0 for example")